# How do I delete the thread under the channel name in discord with python?

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I'm writing a bot to "archive" messages (move them but keep details of author etc) and threads to a specified channel based on date(s).

I'm nearly there but I can't see how to delete the thread that is posted under the channel name:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPyPc.png)

I can delete the messages in the thread after I move them to another channel but I can't see how to delete that thread under the channel.

I had though it was the "THREAD_STARTER_MESSAGE" (and it still may be) but I can't delete that as I get a 403 error saying "Cannot execute action on a system message".

Any suggestions welcome.

BTW - for anyone interested here's what the moved/"archived" messages look like:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/555wO.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.